# Aligning Images with Bullet Points in a Three-Column Layout Using LaTeX

Tags: image, latex

I previously posted this query on [LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705423/aligning-images-with-bullet-points-in-a-three-column-layout-using-latex), but unfortunately, I did not receive any responses. As a result, I'm bringing my question here in hopes of finding a solution to my problem.

I'm working with LaTeX to create a document that has a three-column structure. In my layout, the first column is for topics, the second column contains a list of bullet points, and the third column includes images of varying sizes. Additionally, I want to add a link icon to the bottom right corner of each image to indicate that it's a clickable link.

My LaTeX code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman]{moderncv}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\providecommand{\LyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\firstname{firstName}
\familyname{lastName}
\title{topic}

\address{}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\Csharp}{%
    {\settoheight{\dimen0}{C}C\kern-.05em \resizebox{!}{\dimen0}{\raisebox{\depth}{\#}}}}

\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle  
\vspace{-0.9cm}


\vspace{-0.3cm}
\section{Section}
\vspace{0.2cm}

\cventry{Topic}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
            \item {\normalfont Point3}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{-5cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \raggedleft 
        \raisebox{-0.5\height - 0.3cm}{ 
            \href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}}
        }
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}{}{}



\cventry{Topic}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{-4.855cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \raggedleft 
        \raisebox{-0.5\height}{ 
            \href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.6cm, width=1.8cm]{example-image-a}}
        }
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}{}{}


\cventry{Topic}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
            \item {\normalfont Point3}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{-3.05cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \raggedleft 
        \raisebox{-0.5\height - 0.3cm}{ 
            \href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}}
        }
        \raisebox{-0.5\height - 0.3cm}{ 
            \href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}}
        }
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}{}{}

\cventry{Topic}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{-3.05cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \raggedleft 
        \raisebox{-0.5\height - 0.3cm}{ 
            \href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}}
        }
        \raisebox{-0.5\height - 0.3cm}{ 
            \href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.6cm, width=1.8cm]{example-image-b}}
        }
        \raisebox{-0.5\height - 0.3cm}{ 
            \href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-c}}
        }
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The challenge I'm facing is aligning the images in the third column with the bullet points in the second column. Specifically, I want to achieve three things:

1. Ensure that all images in a row are vertically centered with respect to the bullet points.
2. Align images so that the first image in each row is directly below the first image in the previous row, the second image below the second, and so on.
3. Adding a **small** link icon to the bottom right corner of each image to visually represent that the image is a hyperlink.

I'm facing challenges with the alignment of the images and the addition of the link icon. The images are not aligning as expected with the bullet points, and I'm unsure how to add the link icon effectively.

Ultimately, the intended result should be as follows:
[image]

The ability to adjust the distance between the pictures isn't a crucial factor. Additionally, it is not particularly important to display the icon symbol on each picture. What's more important is ensuring that the pictures are aligned both horizontally and vertically through their centers relative to each other. Additionally, it is essential that the pictures are centered within the bullet point list, maintaining a balanced and symmetrical layout.

I do not know if this is possible to do with LaTeX. I previously sought assistance from ChatGPT 4 regarding my query, but unfortunately, I did not receive a suitable solution. Therefore, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to accomplish these alignments and the addition of the link icon. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

With best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

After thorough investigation, I have developed a solution for the layout and positioning of images in the document.

[image]

The key aspects of this solution are:

1. Horizontal Centering: All pictures will be horizontally centered in relation to their center point. The center of each image aligns nearly perfectly with the listing of the bullet points.
2. Vertical Alignment: Pictures that are positioned below each other will also be centered. The middle points of each image are aligned directly underneath one another, creating a visually coherent vertical line.
3. Adjustable Spacing: The distance between the pictures can be adjusted individually. This flexibility allows for precise control over the spacing, enabling a tailored and aesthetically pleasing layout.

This is the latex code:

```
\section{Section}

\newlength{\tabularcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\tabularcolumnwidth}{7cm}

\newlength{\minipagewidth}
\setlength{\minipagewidth}{2cm}

\newlength{\midoffset}
\setlength{\midoffset}{-0.25cm}


\begin{tabular}{p{\tabularcolumnwidth}ccc}
\cventry{Topic1}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}
&
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm, width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1.5cm}

\begin{tabular}{p{\tabularcolumnwidth}ccc}
\cventry{Topic2}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
            \item {\normalfont Point3}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}
&
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1cm, width=2cm]{example-image-a}}}
    \end{minipage} 
& 
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=2cm, width=1cm]{example-image-b}}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{\tabularcolumnwidth}ccc}
\cventry{Topic3}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
            \item {\normalfont Point3}
            \item {\normalfont Point4}
            \item {\normalfont Point5}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}
&
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm, width=1.3cm]{example-image-a}}}
    \end{minipage} 
& 
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1cm, width=2cm]{example-image-b}}}
    \end{minipage}
& 
    \hspace{1cm}
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=1.8cm]{example-image-c}}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{\tabularcolumnwidth}ccc}
\cventry{Topic4}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
            \item {\normalfont Point3}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}
&
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.8cm, width=1.8cm]{example-image-a}}}
    \end{minipage} 
& 
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \hspace{2cm}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.8cm, width=1.8cm]{example-image-b}}}
    \end{minipage}
& 
    \hspace{1cm}
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.8cm, width=1.8cm]{example-image-c}}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
```

To insert the link icon at the bottom-right corner of an image within a table, utilize the following code snippets.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{\tabularcolumnwidth}ccc}
\cventry{Topic1}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}
&
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \href{https://www.google.com/}{
            \begin{overpic}[width=1.5cm, height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}
                \put(1.5cm-0.5cm,0.0cm){\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm, width=0.5cm]{icon_symbol.png}}}
            \end{overpic}
        }
    \end{minipage}

\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Of course, this code can be improved, but it is a solid start.

This is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman]{moderncv}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\providecommand{\LyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\firstname{firstName}
\familyname{lastName}
\title{topic}

\address{}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\Csharp}{%
    {\settoheight{\dimen0}{C}C\kern-.05em \resizebox{!}{\dimen0}{\raisebox{\depth}{\#}}}}

\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle  

\section{Section}
\vspace{0.2cm}

\newlength{\tabularcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\tabularcolumnwidth}{7cm}

\newlength{\minipagewidth}
\setlength{\minipagewidth}{2cm}

\newlength{\midoffset}
\setlength{\midoffset}{-0.25cm}


\begin{tabular}{p{\tabularcolumnwidth}ccc}
\cventry{Topic1}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}
&
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \href{https://www.google.com/}{
            \begin{overpic}[width=1.5cm, height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}
                \put(1.5cm-0.5cm,0.0cm){\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm, width=0.5cm]{icon_symbol.png}}}
            \end{overpic}
        }
    \end{minipage}

\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{\tabularcolumnwidth}ccc}
\cventry{Topic2}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
            \item {\normalfont Point3}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}
&
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \begin{overpic}[height=1cm, width=2cm]{example-image-a}
            \put(2cm-0.5cm,0.0cm){\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm, width=0.5cm]{icon_symbol.png}}}
        \end{overpic}
    \end{minipage}
& 
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=2cm, width=1cm]{example-image-b}}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{\tabularcolumnwidth}ccc}
\cventry{Topic3}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
            \item {\normalfont Point3}
            \item {\normalfont Point4}
            \item {\normalfont Point5}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}
&
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm, width=1.3cm]{example-image-a}}}
    \end{minipage} 
& 
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1cm, width=2cm]{example-image-b}}}
    \end{minipage}
& 
    \hspace{1cm}
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=1.8cm]{example-image-c}}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{\tabularcolumnwidth}ccc}
\cventry{Topic4}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item {\normalfont Point1}
            \item {\normalfont Point2}
            \item {\normalfont Point3}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}{}{}{}
&
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.8cm, width=1.8cm]{example-image-a}}}
    \end{minipage} 
& 
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \hspace{2cm}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.8cm, width=1.8cm]{example-image-b}}}
    \end{minipage}
& 
    \hspace{1cm}
    \begin{minipage}{\minipagewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{\midoffset}
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\href{https://www.google.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.8cm, width=1.8cm]{example-image-c}}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```